# Dynamic Binding in <option> inside Ember.Select

Tags: ember.js, multi-select

If you look at my brief history of questions, I've seem to have built up a reputation for asking simple questions that I should have figured out the answers to myself, before wasting people's time.  With this one though I'm genuinely stumped and I would greatly appreciate some help, so here goes...

1. I have a multi select list (will eventually use a jquery plugin to make it pretty) that will be populated based on some user criteria (in my example the options are hardcoded, but an example would be a 13 year old shouldn't be able to see rated "Mature" games in my game store).
2. Based on some search criteria (let's say we are searching by publisher, games available in a specific country, etc..) The counts for each multi-select item, should update as the search criteria changes and the counts change. (In my example I just change a value with a timer)

Here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/AMPBb/1/

It seems like there are a few ways I could solve this, like a countBinding on my SelectListItem with a displayText computed property, but I can't actually finish a working example.  The first option that has the changing count is **very** hackerish, but demonstrates the functionality that I'm expecting. I haven't come across an example like this before, so I'm very interested in seeing what the best approach to solving this should be.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a computed property `label` on your `App.SelectListItem` which is defined as follows, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/Y6467/

```js
label: function() {
    var text = this.get('text');
    var value = this.get('value');
    return '%@ (%@)'.fmt(text, value);
}.property('text', 'value').cacheable()
```

Also note that you have to create a valueBinding to your 'App.CountModel.*' in your `App.SelectListItem`.

One more thing about naming convention: concrete instances should be named in `lowerCase`, so it's `App.countModel`. See http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html.